# trouble decoding the serial GPS using readfile function

Tags: c++

i m trying to use readfile function to read the serial port in c++. i manage to open and read the serial port in c++. the problem i facing now is the decoding of data after i read from the serial port. The below are my codes. When i run my code, my loop of decoding could not detect ((*&szChar == '$')), and it exit the loop by printing error. May i know how could i decode the gps data that i read from my serial port? thanks

```
char szChar[100];
int nRet;
DWORD  dwBytesRead = 10;
char   ReadBuffer[BUFFERSIZE] = {0};
nRet = ReadFile(hCom,&szChar,BUFFERSIZE-1,&dwBytesRead,NULL);
if((*&szChar == '$'))
{
    printf("%s\n", &szChar);
}
else
{
    printf("error\n");
```

Comment: Perhaps you could start by just dumping out some of the data you do receive. You might find (for example) that you haven't set the GPS to NMEA mode, so what you're getting looks different.

Comment: i got the msg something like this $GPGGA,123519,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,1,08,0.9,545.4,M,46.9,M,,*47
from reading the serial port. but the problem is i think the &szChar data is all in string rather than the array. is there anyway i could decode it? thanks

Comment: What is the value of szChar[0]? ( initialize the array before a call to ReadFile() and then print szChar[0])

Comment: Worse than the uninitialized input `szChar`, the return value `nRet` isn't checked at all, nor is `dwBytesRead`. If `ReadFile` succeeds, the first `dwBytesRead` chars will be initialized.  But if it fails, neither `dwBytesRead` nor `szChar` should be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say, I find your code *quite* confused and confusing. Just for example, you're creating `szChar` as an array of 100 `char`, and `ReadBuffer` as an array of `BUFFERSIZE` `char`s. When you call `ReadFile`, however, you're passing the base address of szChar with the size given as `BUFFERSIZE`. Unless, by some coincidence, `BUFFERSIZE` happens to equal 100, that looks a lot like a potential buffer overrun.

Then we get to `*&szChar`. This doesn't really make much sense either. From the looks of things, you probably want `szChar[0]` -- but even that's not really a good idea, because you might not receive the data in exactly line-sized pieces. As such, you probably want to scan through the data to find the '$'.

```
int Ret;
DWORD  BytesRead;
char   ReadBuffer[BUFFERSIZE] = {0};
Ret = ReadFile(hCom,ReadBuffer,sizeof(ReadBuffer)-1,&BytesRead,NULL);

ReadBuffer[BytesRead] = '\0';

if (ReadBuffer[0] == '$')
    printf(%s\n", ReadBuffer);
else
    printf("error\n");
```

Comment: thanks jerry for your help.. i would like to ask one question from the above ReadBuffer[0] == '$' is to read the first letter of the string right? if this so, if i want to scan the string of the data can i put the ReadBuffer as a array? thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Jerry: Thanks.. so i edited my code below to decode my data, is it correct way to put my ReadBuffer into another array for checking?

```
char lastCommaPosition;
char  latitudeString[11];
char     stringRead[MAXSIZE]; 
char  tempString[MAXSIZE];
char  *pChar;
char  dummyChar;
float        latitude;
int          latDegrees;
float        latMinutes;
int     numLinesRead;

int Ret,i,j,k; 
  if (ReadBuffer[0] == '$') 
{
    i = 0;
    numLinesRead++;
    stringRead[i] = ReadBuffer;

}
stringRead[i+1] = '\0';



j = 0;
pChar = stringRead;
while(*(pChar+j) != ',') 
{
       tempString[j] = *(pChar+j);
       j++;
 }
 tempString[j] = '\0';


if(tempString[3] == 'G' && tempString[4] == 'G' && tempString[5] == 'A')
{
     pChar = stringRead;


      j = lastCommaPosition + 1;
      k = 0;
      while(*(pChar+j) != ',') 
      {
       latitudeString[k] = *(pChar+j);
       j++;
       k++;
      }
      lastCommaPosition = j;
      latitudeString[k] = '\0';

      sscanf(latitudeString, "%f", &latitude);
      latDegrees = (int)(latitude/100);
      latMinutes = (float)(latitude - latDegrees*100);
      printf("\t%02d DEG\t%2.4f MIN", latDegrees, latMinutes);
```